# What is a good library/language for working with mathematical functions

Tags: math

What are some good libraries for handling mathematical functions. these types of things(Preferably Open Source).

In particular:

- Derivative of a function.
- Solving a function for a particular variable, not always for a real value, but in terms of other variables.

  - Ex. Solving x^2 + y^2 = y for y in terms of x.
- Graphing functions.
- Ability to handle piece-wise functions.

Comment: Language of preference? Any technology limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is symbolic mathmetatics.

[Sympy](http://sympy.org/) is a very good python library for this with very little special syntax to learn.

Answer (score 1):

[scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) or [gsl](http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/)